# Inserir dados na base de dados XAMPP com php

Tags: php, html, sql-insert, xampp

Necessito de inserir os dados que o utilizador põe na página web para a base de dados do XAMPP, mas não estou a conseguir alguem me consegue ajudar?

Código da página na quais são postos os dados:

```
<label>Nome Produto : </label>
<input type=text size=70 name="NomeProduto" value="<?php echo $NomeProduto; ?>">
<br>
<label>Preço Produto : </label>
<input type="number" min="1" step="any" name="PrecoProduto" value="<?php echo $PrecoProduto; ?>">
<br>
<label>Imagem Produto : </label>
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<br>
<label>Descrição Produto : </label>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="DescricaoProduto" value="<?php echo $DescricaoProduto; ?>"></textarea>
<br>
<label>Quantidade Produto : </label>
<select  name="QuantidadeProduto" value="<?php echo $QuantidadeProduto; ?>">
  <option selected data-default>- Indique -</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="16">16</option>
  <option value="17">17</option>
  <option value="18">18</option>
  <option value="19">19</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="21">21</option>
  <option value="22">22</option>
  <option value="23">23</option>
  <option value="24">24</option>
  <option value="25">25</option>
  <option value="26">26</option>
  <option value="27">27</option>
  <option value="28">28</option>
  <option value="29">29</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
  <option value="31">31</option>
  <option value="32">32</option>
  <option value="33">33</option>
  <option value="34">34</option>
  <option value="35">35</option>
  <option value="36">36</option>
  <option value="37">37</option>
  <option value="38">38</option>
  <option value="39">39</option>
  <option value="40">40</option>
  <option value="41">41</option>
  <option value="42">42</option>
  <option value="43">43</option>
  <option value="44">44</option>
  <option value="45">45</option>
  <option value="46">46</option>
  <option value="47">47</option>
  <option value="48">48</option>
  <option value="49">49</option>
  <option value="50">50</option>
  <option value="51">51</option>
  <option value="52">52</option>
  <option value="53">53</option>
  <option value="54">54</option>
  <option value="55">55</option>
  <option value="56">56</option>
  <option value="57">57</option>
  <option value="58">58</option>
  <option value="59">59</option>
  <option value="60">60</option>
  <option value="61">61</option>
  <option value="62">62</option>
  <option value="63">63</option>
  <option value="64">64</option>
  <option value="65">65</option>
  <option value="66">66</option>
  <option value="67">67</option>
  <option value="68">68</option>
  <option value="69">69</option>
  <option value="70">70</option>
  <option value="71">71</option>
  <option value="72">72</option>
  <option value="73">73</option>
  <option value="74">74</option>
  <option value="75">75</option>
  <option value="76">76</option>
  <option value="77">77</option>
  <option value="78">78</option>
  <option value="79">79</option>
  <option value="80">80</option>
  <option value="81">81</option>
  <option value="82">82</option>
  <option value="83">83</option>
  <option value="84">84</option>
  <option value="85">85</option>
  <option value="86">86</option>
  <option value="87">87</option>
  <option value="88">88</option>
  <option value="89">89</option>
  <option value="90">90</option>
  <option value="91">91</option>
  <option value="92">92</option>
  <option value="93">93</option>
  <option value="94">94</option>
  <option value="95">95</option>
  <option value="96">96</option>
  <option value="97">97</option>
  <option value="98">98</option>
  <option value="99">99</option>
  <option value="100">100</option>
</select>
<br>
<label>Categoria Produto : </label>
<select name="CategoriaProduto" value="<?php echo $CategoriaProduto; ?>">
  <option selected data-default>- Selecione -</option>
  <option value="Roupa Desportiva">Roupa Desportiva</option>
  <option value="Futebol">Futebol</option>
  <option value="Basquetebol">Basquetebol</option>
  <option value="Andebol">Andebol</option>
  <option value="Tenis">Tenis</option>
  <option value="Corfebol">Corfebol</option>
</select>
<br>
<button type="submit" class="btn" name="addproducts_btn">Adicionar Produtos</button>
```

Na base de dados tenho os campos

```
$NomeProduto, $PrecoProduto, $DescricaoProduto, $QuantidadeProduto, $CategoriaProduto
```

Comment: Como você está recuperando os dados para inserir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A forma mais fácil de resolver é pela seguinte ajuda: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que eu pude entender você deseja gravar os dados do usuário no banco de dados MySQL correto? Primeiro você deverá criar um banco de dados e uma tabela, você pode fazer isso no phpmyadmin, se estiver utilizando o wampserver ou xampp você pode acessar por `localhost/phpmyadmin` depois você deve inserir utilizando [mysqli](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php) oud [PDO](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php) (Eu recomendo PDO por questões de segurança). Você deve recuperar seus dados do formulário com php e inserir no banco de dados com mysqli ou PDO.

Comment: @JoséGomes você precisa apenas do código php ou preciso do php + mysql?

Comment: @JoséGomes http://www.diogomatheus.com.br/blog/php/trabalhando-com-pdo-no-php/